# How to populate an existing numpy array with specific dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say that I have this initial numpy array with some fixed dtype:

```
array = numpy.array([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')],
                    numpy.dtype([('idfield',numpy.int32),
                                 ('textfield', '|S256')]))
```

Now I need to populate this array in a for loop so I do that

```
for val in value:
    array = np.append(array, np.array([(val[0],val[1])],numpy.dtype([('idfield',numpy.int32),
                                                                     ('textfield', '|S256')])),axis=0)
```

It works but it really doesn't looks good ! I need to re-specified the dtype in the for loop, even if it's logic that i'm going to use the same dtype to populate my array.

Do you know a simpler way to achieve this operation ?

Comment: Why don't you save the `dtype` to a variable rather than creating it anew each time?

Comment: Why are you doing this element by element in a for loop in the first place?

Comment: Your first statement is the correct way to create a multi element structured array - using a list of tuples.  But if you must use concatenate, then all inputs have to be arrays of the correct `dtype`.  It won't work with a mix of arrays and tuples.  Oh, and avoid `np.append`.  It's evil!

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I have the habits to use matlab where we can dynamically allocate an array in a for loop, even if the size of the array is not specified. So I guess that I should change my habits when using python.

Comment: @obchardon. You should change your MATLAB habits as well. What you are doing is bad practice in general. The MATLAB linter will complain about it every time. And where do you see an array of unspecified size?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I should have said "unallocated array". Sometime you're just making a small script where the performance doesn't really matter.

Comment: @obchardon. It's still a bad habit in either language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.append` is a simple cover to `np.concatenate`

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

In [89]: dt = np.dtype('U5,int')
In [90]: arr = np.array([('one',1)], dtype=dt)
In [91]: np.append(arr, ('two',2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-bc17d9ad4a77> in <module>()
----> 1 np.append(arr, ('two',2))
 ...
-> 5166     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

In this case it does

```
In [92]: np.ravel(('two',2))
Out[92]: array(['two', '2'], dtype='<U3')
```

turning the tuple into a 2 element string dtype array.  Now `concatenate` tries to join an array of `dt` with the `U3` array, and it can't.  There's nothing in the `append` uses the `arr.dtype` as the basis for turning `values` into an array.  You need to do that yourself.  `numpy` can only do so much to infer you intentions. :)

So if you specify common the dtype it works:

```
In [93]: np.append(arr, np.array(('two',2),dt))
Out[93]: array([('one', 1), ('two', 2)], dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

I dislike `append` because new users often misuse it.  Usually they think of it as a list append clone, which it is not.

But it does have one advantage - it promotes the dimensions of 0d inputs:

```
In [94]: np.concatenate([arr, np.array(('two',2),dt)])
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Making the 2nd array 1d works:

```
In [95]: np.concatenate([arr, np.array([('two',2)],dt)])
Out[95]: array([('one', 1), ('two', 2)], dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

`append` hides the dimensional adjustment that `concatenate` needs.

But where possible it is better to create a list of arrays (or tuples) and do `concatenate` just once:

```
In [96]: alist = [('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)]
In [97]: ll = [np.array([x],dt) for x in alist]
In [98]: ll
Out[98]: 
[array([('one', 1)], dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')]),
 array([('two', 2)], dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')]),
 array([('three', 3)], dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')])]

In [100]: np.concatenate(ll)
Out[100]: 
array([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

But making the array directly from a list of tuples is even better:

```
In [101]: np.array(alist, dt)
Out[101]: 
array([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still a newcomer in the python world, I'm not thinking like a pythoneer :p. If the best option is making the array directly from a list of tuples I will chose this option. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like @juanpa.arrivillaga commented, it's cleaner to define your dtype only once:

```
array_dt = np.dtype([
    ('idfield', np.int32),
    ('textfield', '|S256')
])
```

Then define your second list of values as an array and then concatenate

```
array2 = np.array(value, array_dt)                                     
array = np.concatenate([array, array2])
```